# Web Browser for Debian on ARM?

Tags: debian, web

I recently installed Debian on my ARM Android tablet. However, I'm having trouble finding a good web browser. I've added the Raspbian repos in addition to the standard Debian repos, but I can't find a web browser to use. The packages of browsers I can install are of very old versions. It seems that nobody compiles ARM versions of popular browsers anymore. I've tried a Ubuntu community version, but it terminates in a seg fault. I've also began to try to build from source, but it always has some missing dependency, and that dependency has its own dependencies, and I end up installing hundreds of packages just to build Midrori, Konqueror, Epiphany, or Chromium. I've also tried Arora, but it also terminates in an error. In desperation I tried [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280599/bash-says-file-not-found-when-ls-and-dir-list-it). Any ideas? I'm running Debian Jessie.

Comment: Well, it doesn't always work right. For instance, it shows me the mobile page of Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have found a solution. I added the `ports.ubuntu.com` repo and set it to `trusty`. It has `armhf` ports of most i386 packages available to Ubuntu. It also includes fairly up-to-date versions of Firefox, Chromium, and other packages. Just don't remove the existing Debian repos and use pinning to set this as a lower priority. Works like a charm!

The repo line to insert into `sources.list` is:
`deb http://ports.ubuntu.com [release] main multiverse restricted universe`

Repeat for `-backports`, `-proposed`, `-updates`, and `-security`.

Comment: Hi, it would be great if you could give exact instructions in the solution.

Comment: So... How do you do that?

Answer (score 1):

You should try Midori browser

```
sudo apt-get install midori
```

It works for me.