# Bash says file not found when `ls` and `dir` list it

Tags: debian, chrome, android, chromium-os

I downloaded the ChromiumOS shell for Linux from [here](https://download-chromium.appspot.com/?platform=Linux_ChromiumOS_Full&type=snapshots), unpacked it, and attempted to run `chrome-wrapper`. However, Bash tells me that the file `chrome`, a shared library according to Thunar, which is also in the same directory, is not found, yet I am staring at it in Thunar. It is also listed in `ls` and `dir`, and I can use `cat` to view it, even though it spits out garbage (of course). When I try to run `chrome` directly, bash once again tells me that the file is not found. Strangely, the File Manager app running on the same Android system as Linux tells me the file in question is 174 MB, while Thunar in Debian tells me it's 813 MB. I'm running Debian Jessie using fake root on ARM Android. Thanks.

Comment: Is `.` in your path?

Comment: Yup. I have bash in the directory where all the Chromium files are.

Comment: It's probably a dynamic linker thing, please include the exact entire error message.

Comment: Here's the exact error message: `bash: ./chrome: No such file or directory.`

Comment: That executable is a x86_64 executable, not a 32 bit ARM executable. You're getting that error because there's no /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 on your system. It can't work as amd64 and ARM are completely different CPU architectures with different instruction sets.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute something from your current location, you need to write `./` before the command. In your case `./chrome`

Calling chrome directly would only work if the current directory is in the PATH environment variable.

Comment: I am aware of that. I do call ./chrome either directly or by calling ./chrome-wrapper, which is in the same directory and is supposed to start chrome correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The directories containing system libraries should to be referenced in `/etc/ld.so.conf`. (If you change those then call `ldconfig` to update the corresponding binary database.)

When you have per-application libraries stored elsewhere you need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to one or more colon-separated directories containing these user libraries.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${PWD:-$(pwd)}"
./some_program
```

Comment: The file in question is not a system library. It is a file that I believe contains the Chromium OS shell compiled for multiple architectures.  The executable `chrome-wrapper` is simply a script that starts the shell contained within the "library."

Comment: @GeoffreyS your question says that thunar identifies `chrome` as a shared library. I had answered on the basis that this was a correct identification.